# Linked Server Problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a MSSQL2008 and MSSQL2005 in my system.All SP's is up-to-date.

2008;

> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (SP2) -
>   10.0.4000.0 (X64) Sep 16 2010 19:43:16 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft
>   Corporation Enterprise Edition
>   (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 
>   (Build 7600: )

2005;

> Microsoft SQL Server 2005 -
>   9.00.4053.00 (Intel X86) May 26 2009 14:24:20 Copyright (c) 1988-2005
>   Microsoft Corporation Workgroup
>   Edition on Windows NT 5.2 (Build 3790:
>   Service Pack 2)

Now,My question is; I setup to linked to SQL Server 2005 from SQL Server 2008 under the Server Object.But,When I query , I am receiving the following error.

```
select * from [192.x.x.x].DBName.dbo.TableName
```

Result;

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for
>   linked server "192.x.x.x" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any
>   information about the error.
>
> Msg 7312, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Invalid use of schema or catalog for
>   OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI10" for linked
>   server "192.x.x.x". A four-part name
>   was supplied, but the provider does
>   not expose the necessary interfaces to
>   use a catalog or schema.

Thanks in advance,

Cheers,

Comment: When you script your linked server, what does it generate please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once came across a similar problem - I've just dug out the [MSDN Blog article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pram/invalid-use-of-schema-or-catalog-for-ole-db-provider-sqlncli-for-linked-server) I used to fix it. Don't know if this will help you too?

Comment: Good call. Somewhat obscure though...

Comment: @milesD, please quote relevant text (or at least a hint) in your answer so that it can benefit others even if/when the provided link no longer works.